# Use iMessage on Mac without signing into iCloud in System Preferences?

Tags: icloud, imac, messages

I would like to use my iMac without iCloud syncing and backup turned on.

The only app that I do use between my iPhone and iMac is Apple Messages with family.

Before I begin toggling switches on my iMac, thought I would ask:

- Can I sign into Messages with my Apple ID (Preferences > Accounts) while not signing in System Preferences > iCloud?
- Would Messages be enabled?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Which macOS version are you on?

Answer (score 3):

You **can** sign into Messages separately to iCloud through Messages → Preferences → Accounts as you mention. You won't be able to use [Messages in iCloud](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208532) unless you also sign into iCloud.

Answer (score 0):

These are different things:

- Use iMessage on Mac without signing into iCloud in System Preferences? (header)
- I would like to use my iMac without iCloud syncing and backup turned on. (first paragraph)

To turn off syncing and backup while signed in with AppleID just deselect respective options in settings.

Apple documentation: [Change your iCloud feature settings](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207689) > Turn iCloud features on or off

Comment: And of course there is no such thing as iCloud Backup on a Mac, that's a iOS thing.